# Azure Machine Learning Data Transformation

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

Can machine learning be used to transform/modifiy a list of numbers.

I have many pairs of binary files read from vehicle ECUs, an original or stock file before the vehicle was tuned, and a modified file which has the engine parameters altered.  The files are basically lists of little or big endian 16 bit numbers.

I was wondering if it is at all possible to feed these pairs of files into machine learning, and for it to take a new stock file and attempt to transform or tune that stock file.

I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me if this is something which is at all possible.  All of the examples I've found appear to make decisions on data rather than do any sort of a transformation.

Also I'm hoping to use azure for this.

Comment: Are you able to create your process from in an experiment? To read your data, I would use the Blob Readers. You will be able to pass in the file paths as web service parameters.

Comment: You can use AML to do any kind of transform that you can express in R or Python. Including transforms learned by ML. But if you want a more detailed answer you will have to give us more details, and it would be best if you tried something first and posted that.

Answer (score 1):

We would need more information about your specific problem to answer.   But, supervised machine learning can take data with a lot of inputs (like your stock file, perhaps) and an output (say a tuned value), and learn the correlations between those inputs and output, and then be able to predict the output for new inputs.  (In machine learning terminology, these inputs are called "features" and the output is called a "label".)

Now, within supervised machine learning, there is a category of algorithms called regression algorithms.  Regression algorithms allow you to predict a number (sounds like what you want).

Now, the issue that I see, if I'm understanding your problem correctly, is that you have a whole list of values to tune.  Two things:

1. Do those values depend on each other and influence each other?  Do any other factors not included in your stock file affect how the numbers should be tuned?  Those will need to be included as features in your model.
2. Regression algorithms predict a single value, so you would need to build a model for each of the values in your stock file that you want to tune.

For more information, you might want to check out [Choosing an Azure Machine Learning Algorithm](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2015/09/08/choosing-an-azure-machine-learning-algorithm.aspx) and [How to choose algorithms for Microsoft Azure Machine Learning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-algorithm-choice/).

Again, I would need to know more about your data to make better suggestions, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Most of the file is empty and most of the data regions will be left unchanged.  In the above link you can see the pink line is the new modified data and the white line is the original data.

But I don't think I can test each value on it's own, they mean nothing separately.

By each value do you mean each point in that trend line?

Comment: I would like the system to recognize the sequence of bytes in the original file as a region it needs to change and for it to have a go at changing that portion of the file to make it look like the pink line.